# Permission error while running ionic cordova app

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, windows-subsystem-for-linux

On running command
 `ionic cordova run android` 
I get the following error

```
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, chmod '/mnt/e/New Course/mycode/ionic/reportingApp/platforms/android/app/src/main/res/xml/config.xml'
    at Object.chmodSync (fs.js:1137:3)
    at copyFileSync (/mnt/e/New Course/mycode/ionic/reportingApp/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/shelljs/src/cp.js:41:6)
    at /mnt/e/New Course/mycode/ionic/reportingApp/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/shelljs/src/cp.js:201:5
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object._cp (/mnt/e/New Course/mycode/ionic/reportingApp/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/shelljs/src/cp.js:157:11)
    at Object.cp (/mnt/e/New Course/mycode/ionic/reportingApp/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/shelljs/src/common.js:186:23)
    at updateConfigFilesFrom (/mnt/e/New Course/mycode/ionic/reportingApp/platforms/android/cordova/lib/prepare.js:98:11)
    at Api.module.exports.prepare (/mnt/e/New Course/mycode/ionic/reportingApp/platforms/android/cordova/lib/prepare.js:42:20)
    at Api.prepare (/mnt/e/New Course/mycode/ionic/reportingApp/platforms/android/cordova/Api.js:192:45)
    at /home/abhijeet/.nvm/versions/node/v13.8.0/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/prepare.js:105:36
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

        cordova prepare android --verbose exited with exit code 1.
```

All the dependencies are well setup seems to be some problem with the file permission but tried changing the permision to 777 and it also does not work.
The command ionic serve works perfectly and the app also works perfectly in the browser.